# Connected components $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\backslash\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a closed piecewise $C^1$ curve $\gamma$, I learned that the index function $n(\gamma,\cdot):\mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$,
$$n(\gamma,z):=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{\xi-z}\,d\xi,$$ is constant on each connected component of $\mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma$. I've read on the Internet this same statement but with $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\backslash\gamma$. I'm not used to working with the Riemann sphere, so my question is: given $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, is there any relation between the connected components of $\mathbb{C}\backslash \Omega$ and of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\backslash \Omega$?